# Are there Relational Topic Model implementations available anywhere other than {lda} Gibbs Sampler?

Tags: r, natural-language, topic-models

Reading the help of CrossValidated about wether or not this question would belong here and StackOverflow it says "if it needs statistical expertise to understand or answer, ask it here". Since this is a more advanced method I opted to post here.

I am trying to find an implementation of Relational Topic Model (RTM) as either described on [the original work](http://www.cs.princeton.edu/~blei/papers/ChangBlei2009.pdf) or one of it's follow-up variations [[1]](http://arxiv.org/abs/1310.2409), [[2]](http://www.ecmlpkdd2013.org/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/280.pdf). I noticed on CRAN there is an RTM version based on Gibbs but the author of the work make it clear it is experimental and differs from the original proposed work [[3]](http://www.inside-r.org/node/64282).

Is there anything else available?

Comment: Don't forget this newer incarnation: https://scholar.google.com/citations?view_op=view_citation&hl=en&user=VGAsUUwAAAAJ&sortby=pubdate&citation_for_view=VGAsUUwAAAAJ:3BLL4iowKW4C

Comment: BTW: I also want this, but I can only find C-code. You should probably download Eclipse IDA and get the C/C++ extension (with Mingw32 compiler). That' show I run these.